# WKWebView add query parameter to tapped link

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` in my app which opens some web pages. There are links in those web pages. If the user taps any of the links, I need to add a parameter to the url e.g. if the tapped url was https://google.com, this should be modified to https://google.com?query=xyz and the navigation should continue.

I had a look into `WKNavigationDelegate` and there is a method

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction preferences:(WKWebpagePreferences *)preferences decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences *))decisionHandler API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15), ios(13.0));
```

This method returns the navigation action which contains the tapped link url in the `URLRequest` but this is not mutable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you inject your query into the URLs in the web page source? You can modify the web page however you like, as it loads.

Comment: We can't inject it because the content for web browser is different and the query has to be added only in case when opened in the iOS app.

Comment: Yes, and WKWebView can take care of that.

Comment: @matt I don't get it, please elaborate how WKWebView cab take care of that? The content for the web browser is different but when opened in WKWebView we need to add a query parameter to the link so that the server send a different content.

Comment: You use JavaScript to modify the page content.

Answer (score 1):

In the `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` you can check the URL the web view tries to load. If the URL doesn't contain the query you want you can cancel the navigation by calling to `decisionHandler(.cancel)`, create a new URL appending the query you need and load the new URL with you query.

This will start the navigation again but now as you detect that the URL contains your query you won't cancel the navigation.

Comment: This will cause the user not be able to come back to the original view when they tap the back button.

Comment: That's not an issue. You always can open the back/forward navigation with:
```if navigationAction.navigationType == .backForward {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
```